# Conservation of angular momentum and collision

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, friction, rotational-kinematics

### The problem:

> Consider a thin ring rolling without slipping (pure rolling)  on a rough surface (means there is friction) with constant velocity $v_0$. The ring hits a vertical wall elastically and bounces off it. When will the ring stop, given the friction coefficient $\mu$?

The answer suggested that the angular velocity will remain the same (lets say that the ring initially moves left with anticlockwise rotation) after hitting the wall and my question is why so?

It will be great if any of you guys has an equation to proof this case. Thanks for any kind of help !

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE. What have you tried so far?

Comment: What specifically you want to know,? what you analyze about the situation,

Comment: Thank you :)  with the assumption that the ring will continue with the same angular velocity but with an opposite direction for the linear velocity, i can use the fact that after the collision there is slipping and i can use the motion equations and torque equations pretty easily to find the time in which the ring will stop moving (v(t1)=w(t1)=0)

Comment: I want to know why after the collision the ring moves with the same angular velocity, in the same direction.

Comment: Work done at the interface is zero since there is no sliping, so the ring will always continue moving.

Comment: If you are querying a given answer you ought to post the complete question and answer because the answer may depend on the exact words used rather than your description of the problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saying that the collision is elastic implies that energy is conserved. It seems unlikely that friction with the wall could reverse the angular velocity.  If we assume no such friction, then there is no torque, and the angular velocity remains unchanged.  After the collision, the linear velocity has been reversed, but the spin is still trying to take the loop in the original direction. It can be shown that the resulting kinetic friction brings both motions to zero at the same time.  (Note:  Vo = R Wo)

Answer (score 1):

The collision is very short in duration and he friction force finite, so the change in the angular velocity is negligible. It is different with the linear velocity, in which the collision is short and the force large (instantaneous collision and infinite force in an idealized case)

Answer (score 0):

That's a weird question. If the ring has no contact time with the wall (meaning we assume both wall and ring are infinitely rigid), then there is no loss of energy. The ring travels the same path length with and without wall.

Answer (score -1):

I do not think that the ring will move with the same angular velocity.

in fact in this case the ring will finally stop any translating and rotating.

Anyway for solving this question

1. write the torque equation in terms of friction and then
2. translatory motion as $V=U-\frac{F*t}{m}$then
3. apply pure rolling condition intitally and finally